# exhaustive type checking in IF-statement

Tags: typescript

I read up about exhaustive type checking and it is really a great feature of typescript. I experimented with it and came across some odd behavior (or not fully implemented by the typescript team).
This is the code I have now (which works great):

```
type factType = 'test-1' | 'test-2'

function doSomething(fact: factType) {
    if (fact ==='test-1') {
        return true;
    } else if(fact === 'test-2') {
        return true;
    }

    assertUnreachable(fact);
}

function assertUnreachable(x: never): never {
    throw new Error("Didn't expect to get here");
}
```

But when I use a function as a branching condition, it breaks. It says "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' fact: "test-2"":

```
type factType = 'test-1' | 'test-2';

function doSomething(fact: factType) {
    if (fact === 'test-1') {
        return true;
    } else if (isTest2(fact)) {
        return true;
    }

    assertUnreachable(fact);
}

function isTest2(fact: factType) {
    return fact === 'test-2';
}
```

I tried using `fact as 'test-2'` but it does not work.
Does anyone know how to fix this or what the reason may be? I think it is Typescript, but I am by no means an expert!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) to indicate to TS that the function checks if `fact` is of type `test-2`.

```
function isTest2(fact: factType): fact is 'test-2' {
    return fact === 'test-2';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also pretty new to exhaustive checking, but most of the times I see it in combination with the `switch` case. The following example works:

```
type factType = 'test-1' | 'test-2';

function doSomething(fact: factType): boolean {
    switch (fact) {
        case 'test-1':
            return true;
        case 'test-2':
            return true;
        default:
            assertUnreachable(fact);
    }
}
```

I guess that when you use a function that can take either 'test-1' or 'test-2' is not the same as using `case` where only one value for the `factType` can be evaluated at a time. By using the `union (|)` you're saying "factType can only be one of these types. Either one or the other."
`assertUnreachable` will make sure all the paths are covered at compile time (yay!). This means that if `factType` would have an additional type, then `assertUnreachable` will have a compile error.

[Adding a new type results in compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3YOx.png)

```
type factType = 'test-1' | 'test-2' | 'test-3';
function doSomethingElse(fact: factType): boolean {
    switch (fact) {
        case 'test-1':
            return true;
        case 'test-2':
            return false;
        default:
            assertUnreachable(fact); // TS2345: Argument of type '"test-3"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the switch case did it for me. Thanks